# Vim paste is pasting some old line copied weeks ago, ignoring current copied line

Tags: vim

Earlier I had a 32-bit system where my Vim (with spf13-bundle) used to work fine. I upgraded it to 64-bit, reusing the `home` folder contents. After moving to 64-bit, I am facing this problem.

If I copy some line from a file using `Ctrl + C` and then pastE in Vim using `Esc + p`, it pastes some line copied weeks ago, instead of my current copied line which I want to paste.

Perhaps, the vim is not taking lines from clipboard. Please help me on this.

**EDIT**

I found following block in my .viminfo :

```
# Registers:
""0 LINE    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
"1  LINE    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
"2  LINE    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
"3  LINE    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
"4  LINE    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
"5  LINE    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
"6  LINE    0

"7  LINE    0
    [DATA STRUCTURE] : Array
"8  LINE    0

"9  LINE    0
    [DATA STRUCTURE] : Array
"-  CHAR    0
    find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.
```

and this is the line `find the number of pairs for which |ai+aj-K| is minimal possible (and this minimal possible value), having the array a[] and the integer K given.` getting pasted again and again instead of actual one.

Answer (score 0):

The paste you are using is not the same as system clipboard.
If you did not install any plug-in, when you press `p`, it is pasting the lines you yank with `y` previously.

If you don't want to install any plug-in, the quickest way is to press `shift + Ins` under insert mode to paste the system clipboard.

Or you can use `*` to access system clipboard. Under normal mode, type `"*p` will do.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Vim's `p`aste command uses the internal *unnamed register*, not the system clipboard. For that, prepend `"+` to the paste command, or

```
:set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

in your `~/.vimrc`. The *spf13* distribution presumably did that (without you knowing), and you got used to that.

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.